Warning: A history supports only one prompt at a time
I am trying to prevent loosing unsaved data im my React app due to browser events such as Refresh, Back navigation. I put <Prompt/> component from react-router-dom to render method. And after that i got warning:
Warning: A history supports only one prompt at a time Error Component Stack
from  Lifecycle (react-router.js). Everything works perfectly but this message in the console annoys me.
<Prompt
  message={() => window.inputEditing ? "Your unsaved edits will be lost. Leave this page anyway?" : true}
/>

Where can it be the problem? Actually in the page there is only one Prompt component all the time. No any Prompt components anywhere. Any ideas would be great. Thanks.
"react-router": "5.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "5.2.0", (tried to update it to 5.3.4 but it didn't help)
"react": "16.14.0"



class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/abc" render={Abc} />
        </Switch>     
      </Router>
    );
  }  
} 

class Abc extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Prompt message="hello world"/>
        <input type='text'/> 
      </>
    );
  }  
} 


Do you know what version of history is installed in your project? You can check using npm list history. In the meantime can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] showing the router, routes, and where/how (all instances) the Prompt component is/are used, and your complete package.json file and/or dependencies? You should also be aware that you are attempting to use UI patterns that are now generally considered poor UI/UX and even anti-pattern. Instead of blocking navigation actions you should just take care of cleaning things up when they do.

¬ react-router-dom@5.2.0
history@4.10.1
¬ react-router@5.2.0
history@4.10.1 deduped

So, i analyzed my code, and despite on another Prompt was absent, i had found such code
this.props.history.block(this.callback);

Deleting of this line fixed the warning. So i need to review Prompt and this.props.history.block usage at the same time.
